# Numpy operation for euclidean distance between multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array, euclidean-distance

I have two numpy arrays. 'A' of size w,h,2 and 'B' with n,2.
In other words, A is a 2-dimensional array of 2D vectors while B is a 1D array of 2D vectors.
What i want as a result is an array of size w,h,n. The last dimension is an n-dimensional vector where each of the components is the euclidean distance between the corresponding vector from A (denoted by the first two dimensions w and h) and the nth vector of B.

I know that i can just loop through w, h and n in python manually and calculate the distance for each element, but i like to know if there is a smart way to do that with numpy operations to increase performance.

I found some similar questions but unfortunately all of those use input arrays of the same dimensionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You could reshape `A` to `2D`, use [`Scipy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) that expects 2D arrays as inputs, get those euclidean distances and finally reshape back to `3D`.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

out = cdist(A.reshape(-1,2),B).reshape(w,h,-1)
```

**Approach #2**

Since, the axis of reduction is of length `2` only, we can just slice the input arrays to save memory on intermediate arrays, like so -

```
np.sqrt((A[...,0,None] - B[:,0])**2 + (A[...,1,None] - B[:,1])**2)
```

**Explanation on `A[...,0,None]` and `A[...,1,None]` :**

With that `None` we are just introducing a new axis at the end of sliced `A`. Well, let's take a small example -

```
In [54]: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5,2))

In [55]: A[...,0].shape
Out[55]: (4, 5)

In [56]: A[...,0,None].shape
Out[56]: (4, 5, 1)

In [57]: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,2))

In [58]: B[:,0].shape
Out[58]: (3,)
```

So, we have :

```
A[...,0,None]  : 4 x 5 x 1 
B[:,0]         :         3
```

That is essentially :

```
A[...,0,None]  : 4 x 5 x 1 
B[:,0]         : 1 x 1 x 3
```

When the subtraction is performed, the singleton dims are [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) corresponding to the dimensions of the other participating arrays -

```
A[...,0,None] - B  : 4 x 5 x 3
```

We repeat this for the second index along the last axis. We add these two arrays after squaring and finally a square-root to get the final eucl. distances.

Comment: Wow. First approach is actually quite easy. Didn't think of that! Regarding approach 2, i am fairly new to numpy, could you elaborate on the slice and index operations? The [...,None,1] thing is really confusing.

Comment: @MarioDekena `A[...,0,None] ` would look more intuitive to what it essentially does. Edited with few comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like i still have a lot to learn regarding numpy ;)

Comment: @MarioDekena Just curious how fast is approach#2 compared to app#1 on your use-case?

Comment: Gonna do some performance testing soon. I will post the results.

Comment: Ok i did the testing. Approach 1 is actually 2.5 times faster then app#2. I tested with different w, h and n. On my system, w,h = 512 and n = 10 took 1.9s with approach 1 and 4.8s with approach 2. Its probably because app#2 uses python arithmetic, while cdist outsources the complete computation to native c.

Comment: @MarioDekena Yeah that must be it! Thanks for testing it out, good to learn about those!